# polymorph relations with pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, polymorphic-relationship

I have a problem with defining polymorphic relations in Laravel.
I have `Skill` model which is shared between two other models `User` and `Class`.
So User can have many skills and Class can have many skills, but skills are not overlaps between them.

So I created a `skills_assoc` table with `skill_id` (which is foreign key to skills table)

I can't properly set Class -> skills() function to get skills related to the class.

table `skills`

- id
- name

table `skills_assoc`

- id
- skill_id - foreign key to skills table
- skillable_id
- skillable_type

My `Class` skills() definition is

```
return $this
            ->morphedByMany(Skill::class, 'skillable', 'skills_assoc', 'skill_id', 'skill_id', 'skill_id');
```

The problem is that when I want to get `$class->skills`
and print query
`$class->skills()->toSql()`
I receive this strange query

```
select * from `skills` 
inner join `skills_assoc` on `skills`.`id` = `skills_assoc`.`skill_id`
where `skills_assoc`.`skill_id` is null and `skills_assoc`.`skillable_type` = ?
```

```
where `skills_assoc`.`skill_id` is null
```

seems very strange, and my collection is empty, can't figure out why.

Please point when I am wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `morphToMany` on `Class` and `User` to retrieve the skills and `morphedByMany` on `Skill` for the inverse of the relationship, you can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

Comment: Thank you @Remul your solution works perfectly, don't know why I didn't see it before. But anyways I'm grateful for the correct answer.

Comment: I added the comment as an answer, if you want to accept it. Also it would be nice if you could edit my answer and add how your relationship methods look now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong relationship methods at the moment.

You should use `morphToMany` on `Class` and `User`, and `morphedByMany` on `Skill`.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations):

> Many-to-many polymorphic relations are slightly more complicated than
> morphOne and morphMany relationships. For example, a blog Post and
> Video model could share a polymorphic relation to a Tag model. Using a
> many-to-many polymorphic relation allows you to have a single list of
> unique tags that are shared across blog posts and videos. First, let's examine the table structure:

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

> Next, we're ready to define the relationships on the model. The Post
> and Video models will both have a tags method that calls the
> morphToMany method on the base Eloquent class:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
    }
}
```

> Next, on the Tag model, you should define a method for each of its
> related models. So, for this example, we will define a posts method
> and a videos method:

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'taggable');
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'taggable');
    }
}
```